# Getting exact address with building number from reverse geocoding

Tags: google-maps, reverse, street-address, geocode

Hello I'm using google maps in a mobile app and I'm using reverse geocoding to get the nearest address given a location(longitude, latitude).

The returned address includes the street address but not the nearest building number in the street address. I'm using [this to do reverse geocoding](http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=longitude,latitude&output=csv&key=your_api_key).

Is there any there way using google maps api to get the nearest building number together with the street address? If not, then is there any other type of word map api were you can use reverse geocoding to get also get the nearest building number?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON (or XML), and it'll give you a lot more information:

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=-112,46&output=json

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=-112,46&output=xml

Comment: Well, I think this is based on were location is on the map. I'm trying to use reverse geocoding for a location inside Egypt so even setting the output type to json or xml did not display the building number.

Comment: Ah, well, I know some countries are less supported.  I once tried to get address-level data for Sri Lanka, but it only managed street-level (if that). Good luck!